# Columna alternativa para usar en un JOIN en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Yo tengo una tabla llamada `liturgia_calendario` con la siguiente estructura:

```
calendario_id     ff_yy      ff_mm      ff_dd      id_liturgia      pre
1                  2018       06         01          198            0
2                  2018       06         02          199            360
```

Y necesito unirla con otra tabla llamada `liturgia` para usar los datos de `col1, col2, ...`. La estructura de dicha tabla es más o menos esta:

```
id_liturgia     col1      col2...
198                  
199                  
...
360
```

Lo que quiero es que:

- Si la columna `pre` en `liturgia_calendario` es igual a `0`, me use el valor de la columna `id_liturgia` para hacer el join.
- Si la columna `pre` en `liturgia_calendario` es distinta de `0`, me use el valor de dicha columna para hacer el join.

En el caso de la 1ª fila, el join se haría usando el valor `198` y en el caso de la 2ª fila, se usaría el valor `350`.

Yo puedo obtener uno u otro valor de la tabla `liturgia_calendario`. Por ejemplo esta consulta funciona para obtener alternativamente una u otra columna bajo el alias `id_liturgia`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (pre = 0)
            THEN id_liturgia
            ELSE pre 
       END AS id_liturgia
FROM liturgia_calendario 
WHERE f_yy=2018 and f_mm=6;
```

Resultado:

```
id_liturgia
198
360
```

Pero cuando lo intento con el `JOIN` no me funciona.

Si escribo la consulta así:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (pre = 0)
            THEN id_liturgia
            ELSE pre 
       END AS id_liturgia
FROM liturgia_calendario lc
INNER JOIN liturgia l ON lc.id_liturgia=l.id_liturgia
WHERE lc.f_yy=2018 and lc.f_mm=6;
```

Me da el error:

> Column 'id_liturgia' in field list is ambiguous

Si le doy otro alias a la columna resultante del `CASE` me da el mismo error:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (pre = 0)
            THEN id_liturgia
            ELSE pre 
       END AS id_liturgiaz
FROM liturgia_calendario lc
INNER JOIN liturgia l ON lc.id_liturgiaz=l.id_liturgia
WHERE lc.f_yy=2018 and lc.f_mm=6;
```

No sé por qué ocurre esto o si hay una mejor forma de lograr lo que quiero.

Comment: El mensaje que parece que en las dos tablas tienes `id_liturgia`. ¿Has probado con `THEN lc.id_liturgia`?

Comment: Por cierto, desde un nivel más formal, en vez de `0` para indicar que `pre` no apunta a `id_liturgia` estaría mejor que fuera `null`. De esa forma podrías definir *foreign keys* desde ambas columnas que facilitarían las queries.

Comment: @SJuan76 haciéndolo como dices no da error, pero no me hace el `JOIN` como yo quiero. En el segundo caso usa el valor `199` y no el valor `360`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con meter la condición en el JOIN/WHERE:

```
SELECT l.id_liturgia
  FROM liturgia_calendario lc
  INNER JOIN liturgia l
    ON ((lc.pre = 0 AND lc.id_liturgia = l.id_liturgia) OR lc.pre = l.id_liturgia)
  WHERE lc.f_yy=2018 and lc.f_mm=6;
```

[Ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c6b42/2)

Comment: SJuan en mi caso concreto no me funciona. Me da dos filas en los casos en que `pre` no es igual a `0`. Cuando aplicaba el filtro de la pregunta me arrojaba tres filas en lugar de dos. Lo he solucionado haciendo la consulta como indicó @PatricioMoracho en su respuesta. De todos modos muchas gracias por tu interés.

Comment: La única posibilidad que veo para que de dos filas en los casos de `pre = 0` es si en `liturgia` tienes una fila con `id_liturgia = 0`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d7f2/1

Comment: SJuan es correcto, había en `liturgia` una fila con `id_liturgia=0`. Tu consulta funciona también de la manera esperada. Ahora mi dilema sería saber cuál de los dos estilos es más óptimo... o si son iguales. Para evitar esos datos erróneos yo he establecido a `NULL` aquellos valores de `pre` que antes eran `0`. [Decías en un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170057/#comment319197_170057) que era más fácil usar esa columna como FK. Yo pensaba lo contrario, que no era bueno que una FK aceptara `NULL`. Es otro tema, pero me quedan esas dudas, quizá lo plantee en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Los dos problemas que tienes parten de un mismo origen: los alias de columnas y como estos son procesados por el motor:

- Cuando usas el mismo nombre de la columna como alias como parte del `JOIN`, el motor no identifica a que te refieres ya que hay dos tablas con el mismo nombre de columna y al no indicar el alias de la tabla te dice que el nombre es ambiguo.
- Cuando usas otro nombre como alias la consulta no te funciona, por que los alias de columna, el motor los "materializa" bien al final del proceso de la consulta. Es decir, en la instancia del `JOIN`, `id_liturgiaz` no existe.

La solución posible pasa por usar una subconsulta para materializar el nuevo alias:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM ( SELECT   CASE WHEN (pre = 0)
                        THEN id_liturgia
                        ELSE pre 
                   END AS id_liturgia
                   FROM liturgia_calendario 
                   WHERE f_yy=2018 and f_mm=6
    ) lc
    INNER JOIN liturgia l 
        ON lc.id_liturgia=l.id_liturgia
```

O bien repitiendo el `CASE` en el `ON`

```
SELECT l.id_liturgia
FROM liturgia_calendario lc
INNER JOIN liturgia l 
    ON l.id_liturgia=(CASE WHEN (lc.pre = 0) THEN lc.id_liturgia ELSE lc.pre END)
WHERE lc.f_yy=2018 and lc.f_mm=6;
```

Comment: Buena observación @SJuan76

Comment: He usado la segunda opción que propones, que me parece más clara, y funciona como esperaba. Muchas gracias.