# ¿Qué diferencia entre CASE ... WHEN y combinación de AND ... OR en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, buenas-prácticas

La duda viene de las respuestas a esta pregunta:

- [Columna alternativa para usar en un JOIN en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/170057/29967)

Se buscaba solución para usar una columna u otra en el `JOIN` entre dos tablas dependiendo de un criterio dado: cuando el valor de la columna `pre` sea igual a `0` se usará la columna `id_liturgia` en el `JOIN`, de lo contrario, se usará `pre`.

Se propusieron **dos soluciones** distintas, que arrojan los resultados esperados:

#### Solución 1: con `AND  ... OR`

```
SELECT l.id_liturgia
  FROM liturgia_calendario lc
  INNER JOIN liturgia l
    ON ((lc.pre = 0 AND lc.id_liturgia = l.id_liturgia) OR lc.pre = l.id_liturgia)
  WHERE lc.f_yy=2018 and lc.f_mm=6;
```

#### Solución 2: con `CASE ... WHEN`

```
SELECT l.id_liturgia
FROM liturgia_calendario lc
INNER JOIN liturgia l 
    ON l.id_liturgia=(CASE WHEN (lc.pre = 0) THEN lc.id_liturgia ELSE lc.pre END)
WHERE lc.f_yy=2018 and lc.f_mm=6;
```

Esta es una *variante*  de la solución 2:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM ( SELECT   CASE WHEN (pre = 0)
                        THEN id_liturgia
                        ELSE pre 
                   END AS id_liturgia
                   FROM liturgia_calendario 
                   WHERE f_yy=2018 and f_mm=6
    ) lc
    INNER JOIN liturgia l 
        ON lc.id_liturgia=l.id_liturgia
```

---

### La pregunta

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre la solución 1 y la solución 2 por ejemplo en cuanto al rendimiento? ¿Habría alguna forma de probarlo? ¿O se puede usar cualquiera de las dos indistintamente?

Comment: Habría que usar un EXPLAIN para ver si el query planner Le pega al índice que debiese haber en pre y en id liturgia en ambos casos, y hacer la comparación generando un tabla de registro_liturgia de cientos de miles de registros aleatorios, básicamente para evitar que la consulta se ejecute completa en memoria, lo cual llevaría a pensar que el enfoque es igualmente instantáneo. Por ejemplo, con cientos de miles de registros en liturgia_calendario, la subconsulta debiera escribir el resultado temporal a disco y resultar más lenta, pero no se notaría con 1000 registros.

Comment: @amenadiel ¿cuando dices *con cientos de miles de registros* te refieres a registros existentes en esa tabla?

Comment: Claro, básicamente generar mucha data aleatoria para obligar al query planner a no ejecutar la query en memoria, lo cual haría si la cantidad de data permitiera hacer tal cosa. Si alcanza a ejecutar en memoria el tiempo sería idéntico creo yo

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor la solución con "AND ... OR"

Esto es debido a que el CASE se evalua una vez se han recuperado los datos. Por lo tanto, no podemos aprovechar los índices para filtrar los datos.

Las soluciones serían idénticas en caso de no disponer de índices en los campos.

Ver: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e9e9d/2

Como se puede apreciar en los explains. En el primer caso hace dos accesos 'index' (lee todo el índice) y tiene un bucle para igualar los resultados.

Sin embargo en el segundo caso para la segunda tabla utiliza un acceso 'ref', lo cual quiere decir que es capaz de filtrar en ese índice.

La segunda query suele tardar entre a 4 a 8 veces menos. Es un ejemplo sencillo, pero debería ser extrapolable a tu caso.